# unable to open software and workspace center in myeclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

When i try opening software and workspace center in myEclipse it gets stuck at 75%

I have the following error in my .log file

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-03-10 12:24:32.109
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3884)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3855)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3476)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.genuitec.pulse.client.targetcfg.collab.ui.view.SoftwareAndWorkspaceBlueprintContent.updateHeaderText(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.pulse.client.targetcfg.collab.ui.view.SoftwareAndWorkspaceBlueprintContent.activeBlueprint(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.pulse.client.targetcfg.collab.ui.view.SoftwareAndWorkspaceBlueprintContent.createControlCenterControl(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.pulse.client.targetcfg.collab.ui.view.SoftwareAndWorkspaceCenter.createControlCenterControl(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.pulse.client.targetcfg.collab.ui.view.SoftwareAndWorkspaceCenter$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: The crash appears to be in MyEclipse code, you may need to try their support.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug fixed in a later release (it was seen with release 8.x). I suggest you update to a later release to get the fix (the 2013 and 2014 releases do away with the Software and Workspace Center altogether, so that would be preferable). The only workaround appears to be to open MyEclipse on a new workspace (in which case, you'll have to import projects from your old workspace).

Comment: Hi Tony, i tried with new workspace.It does not work.I had to reinstall eclipse to get this one resolved